# Python - given a timezone-aware datetime object how do I get a timezone-naive UTC datetime object?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I'm bemused by the fact that in Python datetime.datetime.utcnow() returns a timezone-naive datetime object.  I would expect it to be timezone-aware with UTC as its timezone, but whatever.  In order to convert this to a timezone-aware datetime object I would do the following:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

us_pacific = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
utc_now = datetime.utcnow()
pacific_now = us_pacific.fromutc(utc_now)
```

What I'd like to know now is how to go in the opposite direction.  Given a timezone-aware datetime object, I'd like to get back to the corresponding timezone-naive UTC datetime object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
# First convert back to UTC
utc_time = pacific_now.astimezone(pytz.utc)

# Remove the timezone attribute to make it timezone-naive
utc_time = utc_time.replace(tzinfo=None)
```

Comment: Note that datetime includes `timezone.utc` so `pytz` not needed, thus `from datetime import datetime, timezone` ... `utc_time = pacific_now.astimezone(timezone.utc)` ...